# Is git good to store thousands of small binary files like PDFs and docs?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I believe the git merge compare features will not work with Binary.

But is it safe to store 1000s of small binary files (each less than 50 mb size) in git safely without data corruption? Could you please advice? The purpose is to use it more like a backup tool, with proper staging  and comments.

**An update on my use case**

My use case is somewhat **similar** to (not exactly though) having a safe versioned (commented) backup for scanned copy of old photographs. I scan each copy of the photograph and commit to the origin(github). Once uploaded, I am less likely to change/edit the already uploaded (pushed) photographs. I will usually scan and add more photographs later (often), but I don't change/delete these photos often.

Comment: **Can** you store those files in git? Sure you can. Is this what git was built for? Not at all. Git was not built to be a backup tool and you will have some issues with underlying design principles, such as history is forever. Gits strength is in keeping source code (that is, text files), with merging and so on, but yes, it can safely store binary files. Know that git by itself does not in any way prevent file corruption, like a proper backup tool might.

Comment: That is, git can *tell* you that files have become corrupted but once files become corrupted in your archive, git can not fix them.

Comment: Additionally, git in its naive form store the full copy of each file every time, but it also creates "pack files", which can have delta compression. This compression, however, does not do well with larger binary files so 50mb-ish files will probably grow the git repository really fast, faster than you intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that it is generally *not* OK to store thousands of binary files, which may reach a size of 50MB.  The reason for this is that Git does not do well at versioning binary files.  To understand what is happening here, view a diff from Git for a source code file.  You will see that the diff is represented as a series of *changes* from one version to the next.  The problem which arises with binary files is that Git usually ends up articulating the diff between two versions as deleting the entire content from the old version, and then adding the entire content from the new version.  So, each commit in which a binary file changes takes up a lot of space.  Now, multiply this by the number of binaries you have, and the number commits/changes, and your repository will very quickly bloat and become too large to manage.

So, to reiterate, I recommend *against* using Git as a general purpose repo for large numbers of binary files.  If you want a VCS tool which is well suited for that, consider something like Perforce.  That being said, if the only binaries you need to version are something like 1KB icons, then this is not so bad.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! but what if I don't change/update these binary files often, I just add new files, and I don't often change any files already added, but add new files in future. For example, you can consider it like a scanned copy of old photographs, and I may add more scanned copy of photos later (with proper comments), but I don't change existing scanned copies that already pushed to github.

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that you will never have the need to change _or_ remove these files, then Git might be suitable.  Notice that I mentioned "remove" as well; just because you delete a binary file from a branch would not at all mean that it would be removed from your history.  Rather, that binary file, and _all_ its versions, would still be in the repo.  Adding a binary file to Git is like a marriage.  Once you're in, it's hard to get out.

Comment: So, no `git filter-branch --person-filter 'my ex wife'`? (Although she's kinda binary)

Comment: Thanks Tim, for the insight! I have slightly updated my original question to add my use case too. Yes, occasssionally I may edit/delete files, but I can afford another version of the file to be saved/stored in git, as it is very rarely I may do such edit/delete operation. (maybe 1000 adds, 10 delete/edits).

Comment: I am worried about the file corruption possibility too, since git is not originally made to handle binaries. I hope it still can push/pull/store data without corruption anyway :)

Comment: You should not have to worry about corruption of your data with Git.  Keep in mind that many developers _will_ in fact version images in Git, e.g. say a few dozen small icons (< 20KB) for use in an Android application.  Where you draw the line depends on the size of your images, how large they are, and whether you think you would need to version them often, or maybe remove them at some point.

Comment: thank you Tim! It helps!

Answer (score 0):

No problem with that *in theory*. It is one of git's very explicit characteristics to prevent any file corruption. Go for it.

Being able to diff files is a big plus, of course, but binaries will be safe and clean in your repo.

Comment: I think there _is_ a problem with that.   1000s of binary files each only 1MB in size is already in the realm of GBs worth of data.  Add to this dozens of commits, and the repo will already be starting to bloat.  Generally speaking, we should not be versioning too many binary files in Git.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the insight, I might have assumed too much, I'll look into it more.